# filename is distorted with '$/r' appended to filename

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, php, cron

I am trying to learn linux commands so please bear with any ignorance.
I am creating a file with cut command which is written in Script.sh file. But when the file is created it adds '$/r' to end of the filename. So further operations on the created file does not executes as no file is found with the given name.

`cut somefile.csv -d"," -f1  > file1`

so the file1 is created with name as 'file1$/r/'
Any help is highly appreciated

Edit :

```
cut inputFile -d"," -f6  >file1    
cut inputFile -d"," -f1  >file2    

paste -d"," file1 file2  > result
```

Comment: I think problem occurs from Script.sh file content. We need to see it's content

Comment: Are you talking about the end of the name of the output file, or about the end of each line in the output file?

Comment: to be precise it is 'file1'$'\r'. @steeldriver you may be right but i have tried to create another file and make sure that there are no such illegal characters.

Comment: @sudodus It is in the name of file

Comment: Then I agree with @osakacjupiter that Script.sh is probably the culprit. Please edit your original question to show the content of that file. Indent each line 4 spaces to render it as 'code'.

Comment: @SandeepSuri, Do you mean that the file output file will be `result$/r` according to your edited question? I don't understand how that would happen by `paste` and redirection. Please tell us which **tools** you use **to edit the file `Script.sh`** and **to see the file names**.

Comment: can you please delete the blank line after the "result" if there is. so please press enter after "result" part. and yes, problem may occurs because of your text editor. why don't you use a different text editor just for one time to test?

Comment: Which operating system are you running (Ubuntu or something else), and which shell program (bash or something else)?

Comment: I am using ubuntu in virtual machine. It has inbuilt text editor. but i can see the files created by using ls -l in the terminal. And there is no blank line after the result.

Comment: I also tried with the linux subsystem for linux in windows but with the same results

Comment: sed -i 's/\r//g' script.sh did the work.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the file encoding of the script.

The $/r garbage at the end of the file name is the windows chars for a new line.

If you created the file Script.sh in an windows environment, then copy the text and paste it into a proper UNIX editor, save and try again.